# How to findout component-family and renderer-type of a JSF component

Tags: jsf, renderer

How can I findout the  component-family and the (default) renderer-type of a JSF component?

These information are necessary when (overriding custom renderers) using the following annotation:

```
@FacesRenderer(componentFamily="",rendererType="")
```

I Googled, went throughed the JSF specification and Ed Burn's book, but couldn't find what I wanted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Programmatically, you could find them out by just printing [`UIComponent#getFamily()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getFamily%28%29) and [`UIComponent#getRendererType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getRendererType%28%29).

Documentary, you could find them out by just looking in the javadoc of the component implementation. For example, `<h:inputText>` is represented by the [`HtmlInputText`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlInputText.html) class. The renderer type can be found in the last paragraph of the introductory text of the javadoc:

> By default, the `rendererType` property must be set to "`javax.faces.Text`".

The component family can be found by checking the value of `COMPONENT_FAMILY` constant field value (which is inherited from [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html)). Click your way through the [Fields inherited from class `javax.faces.component.UIInput` - `COMPONENT_FAMILY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#COMPONENT_FAMILY) - [Constant Field Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.component.UIInput.COMPONENT_FAMILY)

> `COMPONENT_FAMILY`    "`javax.faces.Input`"

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem: you *cannot* override the default JSF renderers by the `@FacesRenderer` annotation. The default renderer would always get prededence. This is by design, see also [issue 1748](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/1752). You really need to register them explicitly as `<renderer>` in the `faces-config.xml` the JSF 1.x way.

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.Input</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Text</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.CustomTextRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Comment: This is a detailed, complete and professional answer. Thanks very much and extra thanks for the comments about faces-config.xml configuration. Thanks again BalusC!