# How do I determine the renderer of a built-in component

Tags: jsf-2

I want to create a customized renderer for a built-in component: `<h:selectOneRadio />`
I would like to know, how do I determine the renderer for a built-in component in order to create my own one and extend from it?

I would like to know a mechanism to get it so I could apply it to determine the renderer for any other built-in component and not just for `<h:selectOneRadio />`.

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The renderer class of a standard JSF component is implementation specific (Mojarra and MyFaces have each its own implementation) and is registered as `<renderer>` in the implementation-specific `faces-config.xml` (or an artifact of it).

To find it out, you basically need to know the component family and renderer type first, so that you can lookup the renderer class in the implementation-specific `faces-config.xml` file youself.

Your starting point is [the `javax.faces.component.html` package summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/package-summary.html). The `<h:selectOneRadio>` is represented by the [`HtmlSelectOneRadio`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlSelectOneRadio.html) component class. The introductory text of [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlSelectOneRadio.html) says:

> By default, the rendererType property must be set to "`javax.faces.Radio`".

There is the renderer type.

The component family is specified as `COMPONENT_FAMILY` constant under "Fields inherited from `UISelectOne`" section of [the very same javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlSelectOneRadio.html#field.summary). Click through to ["Constant field values"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.component.UISelectOne.COMPONENT_FAMILY):

> `public static final java.lang.String`    `COMPONENT_FAMILY`  "`javax.faces.SelectOne`"

There is the component family.

Now, we should look in the implementation-specific `faces-config.xml` file (or an artifact of it). Its location/name is unfortunately nowhere documented, but I can tell that in case of Mojarra it is the `com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml` file in the implementation JAR file (you can extract JAR files with a zip tool). Open it and look for a `<renderer>` entry matching the component family `javax.faces.SelectOne` and renderer type `javax.faces.Radio`:

```xml
<renderer>
    <component-family>javax.faces.SelectOne</component-family>
    <renderer-type>javax.faces.Radio</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>
         com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.RadioRenderer
    </renderer-class>
</renderer>
```

Finally there is it: the [`com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.RadioRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/RadioRenderer.java).

Please note that extending exactly that class tight couples your custom renderer to the specific JSF implementation. Your renderer would not be reuseable on a different implementation such as MyFaces. To be implementation independent, you'd need to write the entire renderer yourself which extends `javax.faces.renderer.Renderer`.

#### See also:

- [How to findout component-family and renderer-type of a JSF component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912476/how-to-findout-component-family-and-renderer-type-of-a-jsf-component)
- [What is the relationship between component family, component type and renderer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076625/jsf-what-is-the-relationship-between-component-family-component-type-and-rend)