# Naming conventions for `<component-family>` and `<renderer-type>` while creating custom JSF components

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I am learning to create custom JSF components and have been successful in creating simple ones. One thing I would like to know is that whether there are any naming conventions to be followed while defining  `<component-family>` and `<renderer-type>` for your component?

For e.g. for combo box the `<component-family>` is `javax.faces.SelectOne`. It looks like a Java class but I was unable to find any such class in JSF API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do indeed not necessarily represent class names. They are just identifiers. The `javax.faces` prefix hints in this case merely that it's part of standard JSF API. The same prefix is used [everywhere else in standard JSF API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces). PrimeFaces components use `org.primefaces` prefix, OmniFaces components use `org.omnifaces` prefix, etcetera.

You're **fully free** in choosing your own for your component library. You should only gurarantee that it shouldn't possibly conflict with a 3rd party one which may be mixed by the enduser. Like as with package structure of Java classes, it'd make sense if you choose for `com.naveen` prefix or whatever what/who represents the owner/developer of the component library.

The same approach as Java packages (and Internet domain names) is a very sensible way of guaranteeing uniqueness (you know, *identifiers* are supposed to be *unique*).

#### See also:

- [How do I determine the renderer of a built-in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831294/how-do-i-determine-the-renderer-of-a-built-in-component/)
- [What is the relationship between component family, component type and renderer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076625/what-is-the-relationship-between-component-family-component-type-and-renderer-t/8079296#8079296)
- [Java packages com and org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125293/java-packages-com-and-org/2125298#2125298)

Comment: So for differentiation `com.naveen.family.XXXXX` and `com.naveen.renderertype.XXXXX` would be a better option, right?