# Custom renderer for PrimeFaces component not registering

Tags: jsf, primefaces, custom-renderer

I've written a custom Renderer Class to fix Primefaces issue#5869 and am now trying to use it on the website I'm working on. I've done so by including

```
<renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>at.ac.uibk.library.utils.fixedInputTextRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
```

in my faces-config.xml.
But it's still possible to insert more than the specified character limit with js.

I added these lines in the fixedInputTextRenderer which should do the necessary check

```
if (submittedValue != null) {
        int maxlength = inputText.getMaxlength();

        if (maxlength > 0 && submittedValue.length() > maxlength) {
            submittedValue = submittedValue.substring(0, maxlength);
        }
        inputText.setSubmittedValue(submittedValue);
    }
```

Comment: Why not report this at https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specified `<renderer-type>` is wrong:

```xml
<renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer</renderer-type>
```

According to the [VDL documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/8.0/) of [`<p:inputText>`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/8.0/primefaces-p/inputText.html) it's by default registered on `org.primefaces.component.InputTextRenderer`.

> **Component information**
>
> | Info | Value |
> | --- | --- |
> | Component Type | `org.primefaces.component.InputText` |
> | Handler Class | *None* |
> | Renderer Type | `org.primefaces.component.InputTextRenderer` |
> | Description | *None* |

So adjust it accordingly:

```xml
<renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.InputTextRenderer</renderer-type>
```

Do note that the component type and renderer type don't actually represent FQNs, but that they are merely keys/identifiers. That they look like FQNs is indeed an unfortunate side effect of enforcing uniqueness which may indeed be confusing for starters.

#### See also:

- [What is the relationship between component family, component type and renderer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076625/what-is-the-relationship-between-component-family-component-type-and-renderer-t)
- [How to findout component-family and renderer-type of a JSF component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912476/how-to-findout-component-family-and-renderer-type-of-a-jsf-component/)